# Call The Same WCF Service From Multiples Hosted Servers

Tags: c#, wcf

I am a little consused with how to acomplish this task. The question is, How can I Call a WCF Services from Multiples Hosted Servers.  The WCF is the same for all the Hosted Apps.  Same Contract, Same Binding Type, Etc.  I am trying to call it in this way because I will host the services in multiples Servers and I need the service to do the same in all of them.  I have to call it from one client. VS 2010, .Net Framework 4.0., C#.

Thanks,

Comment: Jose, do you mean you want to connect to different servers and call the same WCF service on all of them one after the other? Do you have the server addresses and are they mostly static?

Comment: Yes Davide, that is.  The server addresses are given for me.  so, I only need to figure out how could I code the client part for call the service from any of the server or for all if needed, one after the other as you said.  Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends how you plan to create service proxy in the client application. If you want to add service reference it is enough to add it from one server and then create separate endpoint configuration for other servers - all endpoints configurations will exactly same except the address (you can do the same in code). When you call services you will create proxy instance for each server and you will pass name of the endpoint (defined in configuration) for each server like:

```
 foreach(var endpointName in myStoredEndpointNames)
 {
   var proxy = new MyServiceProxy(endpointName);
   proxy.CallSomeOperation();
 }
```

Another approach is not using add service reference. In such case you must share contracts between server and client application and you can use [ChannelFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734681.aspx). This class is factory for client proxies which are created by calling `CreateChannel`. You can pass endpoint configuration name, [endpoint address](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms575251.aspx) or [binding and endpoint address](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa344556.aspx) when calling this method.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I Used Add reference for the proxy. the binding type is a net.tcp binding, the fact is that as I know I could not setup a Client Endpoint for each server in the same configuration file for the same type of binding. wich is what I need to aply the sample above or Could I? sorry for my lack of knowledge, but this is my first WCF Service and I am still a litle out the track.

Comment: @Jose: You can configure as many endpoints as you need but your client proxy instance can use only one. That is the reason why you need to pass name of the endpoint configuration into the proxy constructor. If you don't pass the name and you have multiple ednpoints defined for the same contract you will get exception because of ambiguity.

Comment: Ok, Thanks a lot Ladislav, so, I could Configure 1 net.tcp endpoint for each one of the servers, somenthing like net.tcp://server1/myService     net.tcp://server2/myService etc. and then I just call the endpoint that i need, right?

Comment: Yes. Each endpoint must have unique name and you will use the name for referencing the configuration.

Comment: Thanks Ladislav, using your suggestion of ChannelFactory I could acomplish what I need.  I Learn a lot with this question.

Answer (score 1):

I use a function like this:

```
public static MyWcfClientType GetWcFClient(string hostName)
{
    MyWcfClientType client = new MyWcfClientType();

    // Build a new URI object using the given hostname
    UriBuilder uriBld = new UriBuilder(client.Endpoint.Address.Uri);
    uriBld.Host = hostName;

    // Set a new endpoint address into the client
    client.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(uriBld.ToString());
    return client;
}
```

Of course use your own type for the "MyWcfClientType"

Comment: I will give a try to this function, cause it is almost what I need.  and then I will let you know what is going on. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, eventhought I do not use your approach, but I really Appreciate your time and your answer.